# Simple type annotations in tern.js

Tags: autocomplete, content-assist, ternjs

I have been looking for a while for a tern.js plugin that would allow me to use simple inline type annotations like this:

```
var f = function(/* string */ a) { ... }
```

This is a simple style that, for instance, Brackets supports.

I am aware that I can use JSDoc plugin with tern.js, but that requires a little more verbose syntax, that is especially difficult to use in anonymous functions.

Can I make JSDoc plugin parse these simple annotations or is there another plugin for that?